# Phrasal verbs with the verb PUT

Tags: prepositions

Lately, I have been trying to figure out the difference between these two phrasal verbs when used with commercials

> To put something IN a commercial
>
> To put something ON a commercial

And I still have not grasped the difference between IN and ON when used with put in these situations

Could you point out the difference?

Comment: put in a commercial is not a phrasal verb there.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, almost all phrasal verb + particle combinations can be used non-phrasally.

For example:

> I kicked out my ex-wife = I compelled my ex-wife to leave.

> I kicked out the wall = I kicked the wall which caused it to be removed partially or completely.

The meanings will depend on context.

*Put on X* means to wear X.  This works if it's expressed as *put X on*.

*Put in X for/on Y* means to contribute X towards Y.  *Put X in Y* doesn't usually mean this though.

So both your examples are not a phrasal *put* - it's just *put* being used normally.

---

That being said, you might what to know the difference between *in* and *on*.  They don't mean anything substantially different in your examples and I'll explain.

X is *in* Y if it's surrounded on all sides by Y.  This can be in a 3D sense where you are *in* a room or box, or a 2D sense where you are *in* an area or something delineated by lines, or even a 1D sense where a point is *in* a line defined by two other points.  If *Y* is a container, something can be *in Y*.

X is *on* Y if it overlaps Y physically and Y is below/behind X.  So you can sit *on* a chair, walk *on* the ground, etc.  *On Y" is also used if we physically do something to the surface of Y, so you'll apply makeup *on* your lips, draw *on* the sidewalk using chalk, or paint *on* the side of a building.

So why can we say "in a commercial" or "on a commercial" and mean the same?  It's because multiple models work with the concept of a commercial.

- A commercial has "borders" - a start time and an end time, and various clips and such will make the commercial.  So it's a container, and therefore content can be *in* it.
- Is a commercial a "surface" things can be laid on?  Yes - a creative person might think of a commercial as a blank slate or canvas on which things are placed.

So that's why *in* and *on* both work.

Answer (score 0):

This question would be greatly helped by actual examples. It is difficult to come up with a realistic scenario where "put on a commercial" would arise.

> They put his endorsement in the commercial

simply means

> They added his endorsement to the content of the commercial.

Nor is "put his endorsement in a commercial" include the phrasal verb "put in." The verb is simply "put."

There is a phrasal verb of "put on" that means to "present," particularly in the context of presenting a play on stage.

> They put on "Much Ado About Nothing"

means

> They presented the play called "Much Ado About Nothing."

I have never seen that usage with reference to a commercial, but I suppose it's remotely possible.

Of course, "put" is also a stand-alone verb that can take various prepositions, including "on."

> They put the commercial on television

does not involve a phrasal verb and means

> They displayed the commercial using the medium of television.

Comment: In addition to ***to put on = to present***, there's also ***He's just putting you on*** *(=teasing)*. But I don't know if there are any native speakers who reduce ***upon*** to just ***on*** in the context of ***I don't want to put upon you*** *(=to impose, be a burden)*. Whatever - to my mind, these are "real" phrasal verbs, whereas OP's cited usages aren't.

Comment: Yes. I missed that one. It is not that common in the U.S., but it is far from rare.